# Definition for symbol not found when embedding swc

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, swc

When i embed the symbol "Tile" from swf, it works ok, when i try embedding the same symbol from swc, FlashDebugger throws this error:

```
Error: definition for symbol 'Tile' not found
[Embed(source="../lib/assets.swc", symbol="Tile", mimeType="application/x-shockwave-flash")]
Error: Unable to transcode ../lib/assets.swc.
```

Comment: Why do you use swc? May be change it to swf? I dont see need to use swc in this case

Comment: either your symbol definition or the path to the swc is wrong

Comment: The question is: when it's ok to embed SWFs and when to embed SWCs ?

Comment: Then, you should update your question for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why use swc http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_30.html
2. An example for importing swc file : [Embedding/importing SWC at compile-time in ActionScript, without setting a library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284985/embedding-importing-swc-at-compile-time-in-actionscript-without-setting-a-libra)
3. As per your comment on which one is better : [Flex graphic assets: SWF or SWC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164162/flex-graphic-assets-swf-or-swc)